# Get TopLeft and BottomRight from MKCoordinateRegion MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion, mkcoordinatespan

I checked the properties in documentation for `MKCoordinateRegion`, `MKCoordinateSpan` and `MKMapView` to see there is a way to get the **TopLeft** and **BottomRight** Lat Long from the map view and I didn't find any. I know that the span gives me the Lat long delta but is there a way to get the actual **TopLeft** and **BottomRight** lat longs from map view without having to do weird calculations?

I found [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831634/how-to-get-left-top-and-right-buttom-latitude-and-longitude-of-map-in-mapkit)

Not sure if that is accurate enough. Any votes for that?

Answer (score 29):

I don't think these calculations qualify as weird:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = region.center;
CLLocationCoordinate2D northWestCorner, southEastCorner;
northWestCorner.latitude  = center.latitude  + (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
northWestCorner.longitude = center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
southEastCorner.latitude  = center.latitude  - (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
southEastCorner.longitude = center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, Andriy. I updated the code above so it should be correct now.

Comment: Doesn't this code break if the region crosses either the International date line or the poles?

Answer (score 7):

Straightforward calculations implemented in **Swift 3.0** as extension:

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    var northWest: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + span.latitudeDelta  / 2,
                                      longitude: center.longitude - span.longitudeDelta / 2)
    }
    var northEast: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + span.latitudeDelta  / 2,
                                      longitude: center.longitude + span.longitudeDelta / 2)
    }
    var southWest: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - span.latitudeDelta  / 2,
                                      longitude: center.longitude - span.longitudeDelta / 2)
    }
    var southEast: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - span.latitudeDelta  / 2,
                                      longitude: center.longitude + span.longitudeDelta / 2)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var region: MKCoordinateRegion = ... some region here
print("North - West", region.northWest)
```

Comment: @CarlHung Do you mean west and east were mixed up? If so I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got the +- right? I did not get useful results with that. When I switched the +-, I did. Might be my code is flawed somewhere else, though ;)

Longitude is given as an angular measurement ranging from 0° at the Prime Meridian to +180° eastward and −180° westward. The Greek letter λ (lambda),[3][4] is used to denote the location of a place on Earth east or west of the Prime Meridian.

Technically, latitude is an angular measurement in degrees (marked with °) ranging from 0° at the equator (low latitude) to 90° at the poles (90° N or +90° for the North Pole and 90° S or −90° for the South Pole).

(Wikipedia)