# Get latitude and longitude of centre of MKMapView

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I want when user click on button that exist in center of map , map be locked and I get latitude and longitude of map , in fact get center of map
I don't want use google map or Mapbox I Want to use map kit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784742/converting-view-points-to-mkmapview-coordinates

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read [ask], create a [mcve] and add the _relevant_ code to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
@IBAction func aaa(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude)
    print(self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude)
}
```