# Getting the left-center or right-center point on a Google Maps map

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, google-maps

Currently I can retrieve the center point of the map using

```
new google.maps.LatLng(map.getCenter().lat(), map.getCenter().lng());
```

What I am now trying to do, is get the left-center OR the right-center point of the map. For example:
[Link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SkuH.png)

As far as I know, there is no built in Google Maps API function to retrieve either of these points.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831634/how-to-get-left-top-and-right-buttom-latitude-and-longitude-of-map-in-mapkit

Comment: @HemaNandagopal The link you posted is using Swift and mapkit. As you could have seen from the tags I'm using Google Maps API, not mapkit and Javascript, not Swift. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bound

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();

var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

then get the middle of the lats and lngs

```
eg in Nothern - Western area (otherwise check for min and max lat and lng): 

middleLat = sw.lat() + ( ne.lat() - sw.lat())/2;
```

your left center is in

```
(middleLat, sw.lng() )
```

you right center is in

```
 (middleLat, ne.lng() )
```